# Sitecore 9 as offline installer

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, habitat

I have to setup Sitecore 9 Update 1 on the VM machine where no internet is available due to company policies. I have installed rest of the dependent tools like VS 2017, SQL Server 2017, SOLR and other dependent software. But when I am trying to install Sitecore 9 through install.ps script I am getting nuget related error.

Do anybody know how to install Sitecore 9 as offline installer?

Comment: What nuget related error are you getting? Do you see any parameter that allows changing nuget source to local folder instead of online?

Comment: @grg .. can you please suggest where exactly I have to change the parameter and with what value? I am referring this install script https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/install-xp0.ps1 .

Comment: I'm suspecting that $AssetsPSRepository in https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/settings.ps1 is your problem, right? If that's the case then change the setting to the local folder that contains all required Sitecore packages.

Comment: Please add exact exception so anybody searching for resolution can quickly find it based on error message. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the script that is trying to download nuget packages:

```
function Install-Assets {
    #Register Assets PowerShell Repository
    if ((Get-PSRepository | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $AssetsPSRepositoryName}).count -eq 0) {
        Register-PSRepository -Name $AssetsPSRepositoryName -SourceLocation $AssetsPSRepository -InstallationPolicy Trusted
}
```

You can overcome this to make it offline by:

1. Downloading "Sitecore Installation Framework" and "Sitecore Fundamentals" packages from [Sitecore SIF Download site](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework/1x/Sitecore_Installation_Framework_12.aspx) from Manual Downloads section. Below picture is just illustration. You should download latest version SIF 1.2 -> [image]
2. Unzip downloaded packages and remove version number from the end of folder names so you end up with two folders with names SitecoreFundamentals
   and SitecoreInstallFramework.
3. Move folders created in step 2 under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules on remote server. Folder with Modules should look like this at the end -> [image]
4. Remove this from ps1 script that you are referencing:

   if ((Get-PSRepository | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $AssetsPSRepositoryName}).count -eq 0) {
            Register-PSRepository -Name $AssetsPSRepositoryName -SourceLocation $AssetsPSRepository -InstallationPolicy Trusted

You can follow my blog post with more detailed steps how to do this:
http://tothecore.sk/2018/02/06/installing-sitecore-9-0-1-part-3-3-installing-sitecore-using-sif

Comment: Thanks Peter for your steps. I tried these steps and steps mentioned on your blog. But out of luck. Later on I have requested internet for one day on that VM and after that able to install Sitecore 9. I think we can't installed Sitecore 9 update 1 without internet.

Comment: Could be there is another call outside to download other dependencies. I have focused my answer to your particular problem